# Cordova - Open in external application but how?

Tags: ios, cordova

i just want to know how i am able to set an application for "Open in..." Dialog which is shown when you do a long-tap on a file inside an e-mail for example.

Cause i don't know how to name this "feature" i didn't found anything inside the www or on stackoverflow and i hope, you can help me.

What i mean is this -> [image]

"In A/B/C öffnen"  is where i want to place my application.

Comment: You have to register the file types your app support https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Comment: Do you know a plugin for that? As not, you can post your comment as an answer - that already helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the file type your app support (on the info.plist)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

There is no plugin for this, you can create a "dummy" plugin without native code but on the plugin.xml you put this code for writing on the info.plist:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="*">
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>My File Format</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>MySmallIcon.png</string>
                <string>MyLargeIcon.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.example.myformat</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
        </dict>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```